# Return code and status from PowerShell command

Tags: powershell

I'm running the following command from within a Microsoft System Centre Orchestrator PowerShell activity:

`Install-WindowsFeature -ConfigurationFilePath C:\DeploymentConfigTemplate.xml -ComputerName ServerXYZ`

the command isn't doing what it's supposed to do, and I want to be able to return if the command was successful or not, and any error message if possible.  Ignore the fact it's running in Orchestrator, as I'm more concerned about the PowerShell question.  When I run the command from ISE it does what it's supposed to do, that's why I want to see what is returned from PowerShell.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what may be happening without more context. The following will record any errors encountered in an xml file that you can import later with import-clixml:

```
Install-WindowsFeature -ConfigurationFilePath C:\DeploymentConfigTemplate.xml -ComputerName ServerXYZ
IF (!($?)) {
    $error[0] | export-clixml C:\myerror.xml
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Forget about the xml stuff.  I just want to know if the `Install-WindowsFeature` command is success or not and if a return message is displayed. Maybe displayed with `Write-Host`...

Answer (score 0):

This solves my problem:

```
$Result = Install-WindowsFeature -Name SNMP-Service -IncludeAllSubFeature -IncludeManagementTools
Write-Host $Result.ExitCode
```